# Why would upgrading from Java 8 to Java 17 require me to use the maven-war-plugin?

Tags: maven, war

I am upgrading a project from Java 8 to Java 17 and I am receiving the error (in a pom.xml file) "Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer". I have updated the other dependencies in the pom file as part of the upgrade process as well. I have seen in other stack overflow posts that say this could mean one should update the maven-war-plugin. The thing is, I am not currently using that plugin. When I add it, it does fix the issue, but I am just wondering why that would be.

Comment: Please show us the POM. If you are building a WAR, you most likely use the WAR plugin implicitly even if you have not mentioned it in your POM.

Comment: Yes, I am building a WAR. I was just confused why I didn't need to specify it implicitly with java 8 but I do with java 17. I am very sorry, but I cannot post the pom as it is copy protected. Perhaps I should take the question down?

Comment: Can you explain this: `The thing is, I am not currently using that plugin. ` how are you building a WAR? Using maven-antrun-plugin/maven-assembly-plugin ? Or how?

Comment: I have this present <packaging>war</packaging>, but I do not have a war dependency.

Comment: If you use the correct `<packaging>war</packaging>` than you are using the maven-war-plugin because it's bound to the life cycle by default...(https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging) and yes you don't have defined a dependency to the maven-war-plugin but you are using it. To Upgrade that you should define the most recent version (maven.apache.org/plugins) in a pluginManagement part https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugin-management

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out. All of the errors are now gone. I just am still confused as to why I had to specify a plugin that was not previously specified. I guess what I am wondering is if there is another item that I might be missing during this upgrade that should be upgraded as well (such as the model version?) that this plugin was being carried along with.

Comment: In general all used plugin during the plugin should be defined which means at least define the used version.. (usualy the most recent version)...

Comment: Aright, that sounds good. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the following happened.

When you build a WAR, then the Maven War Plugin is called implicitly (you can see that in the logs).

For some reason, the version was older than the newest available version (maybe a caching problem, maybe parent POM etc.). By explictly setting the version of the Maven War Plugin, this problem vanishes.

Comment: This appears to be the case.

Comment: @ConfusedUbuntist Like the other comments state, maven uses (semi hidden) [default plugins](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-core/default-bindings.html) for every stage. Not to be confused with the [super pom](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html). The version of these plugins depends on your maven version. So the options are either to upgrade your maven version, or add an explicit newer version of the plugin as suggested by this answer. You can view the specific added plugin versions of your current maven version by running `mvn help:effective-pom`.

Answer (score 1):

In my pom.xml, I have added the below code to fix the error.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>
```

And don't forgot to add the war dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```